# Openlayer 2.x clustering

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to use attribute clustering described [here](http://dev.openlayers.org/examples/strategy-cluster-extended.html). I have copied the `OpenLayers.Strategy.AttributeCluster =...` fragment. Here is my code:

```
styleMap = new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
  label: "${labelText}",
  fontColor: "blue",
  fontSize: "12px",
  fontFamily: "Courier New, monospace",
  fontWeight: "bold",
  labelAlign: "lc",
  labelXOffset: "14",
  labelYOffset: "0",
  labelOutlineColor: "white",
  labelOutlineWidth: 3,
  //fillColor: "#ee9900",
  fillColor: "${fillColor}",
  fillOpacity: 0.3,
  stroke: false
});
strategies.push(new OpenLayers.Strategy.AttributeCluster({
  attribute: 'obs'
}));
var vectorLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Overlay", {
  styleMap: styleMap,
  strategies: strategies
});
map.addLayer(vectorLayer);
```

I'm creating features in the following way:

```
var circle = new OpenLayers.Geometry.Polygon.createRegularPolygon(
        new OpenLayers.Geometry.Point( dataArr[i][2],dataArr[i][1]).transform(epsg4326, projectTo), 100, 20, 0);
    var feature = new OpenLayers.Feature.Vector(circle, {labelText: dataArr[i][0], all: dataArr[i][5],ami: dataArr[i][6],obs: dataArr[i][3], fillColor: areaColors[dataArr[i][3]]});
```

and then I add features to the layer:

```
vectorLayer.addFeatures(features);
```

When I run my page, only labels are visible(without circle) but on zooming in and out no features are clustered. What am I missing in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the "pointRadius" property to your StyleMap, as clustering draws points instead of your polygon features.